# SpringAMQP - How to catch ListenerExecutionFailedException?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have 3 queue.

**Queue main**

**Queue retry(3x controlled by the code)**

**Queue to save error messages after 3 attempt.**

It's working fine... but if I sent wrong json message for any reason like:

```
{
"name":"alan","  <<<< this ," is wrong for example
"age":29,
}
```

my listener do not try to process the message(I would like to catch this message because if i got error I'll send to error queue)

I got ListenerExecutionFailedException and than I lost this message.

I tried to add error handler to my config:

```
@Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(RabbitProperties properties, ObjectProvider<ConnectionNameStrategy> connectionNameStrategy) throws Exception {
        PropertyMapper map = PropertyMapper.get();
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory(properties, connectionNameStrategy));
        factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        **factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());**
        RabbitProperties.Listener listener = properties.getListener();
        if (listener != null && listener.getSimple() != null) {
            map.from(listener.getSimple()::getConcurrency).whenNonNull().to(factory::setConcurrentConsumers);
            map.from(listener.getSimple()::getMaxConcurrency).whenNonNull().to(factory::setMaxConcurrentConsumers);
            map.from(listener.getSimple()::getDefaultRequeueRejected).whenNonNull().to(factory::setDefaultRequeueRejected);

        }
        return factory;
    }

public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(new ListenerExceptionHandler());
    }
```

```
@Log4j2
public class ListenerExceptionHandler extends ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isFatal(Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof ListenerExecutionFailedException) {
            ListenerExecutionFailedException lefe = (ListenerExecutionFailedException) t;
            log.error("Failed to process inbound message from queue {}, failed message={}",
                    lefe.getFailedMessage().getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue(),
                    lefe.getFailedMessage());
        }
        return super.isFatal(t);
    }

}
```

I just would like if is possible catch this ListenerExecutionFailedException on my listener..is possible?

because in my handler class I can't do anything.. just set logs.. I can't send this message to the error queue.

listener:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = Queues.MAIN, concurrency = "2")
public void listenerMessage(Message message,@Header(name = "x-death", required = false) List<Map<String, ?>> xDeath) {
    log.info("ProcessMessage Received:: {}", message.getPayload());
    validateReceivedMessage(xDeath, message);
}
```

I tried to add try/catch like:

```
try {

}catch (ListenerExecutionFailedException e){

}
```

without success.

Any suggestion ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

No; message conversion exceptions occur too far down in the stack; there is no way to call the listener with a message that fails conversion.

Such exceptions are considered fatal to avoid an infinite loop; you would need to configure a dead letter exchange and routing key on the original queue so the failed message is routed there.